# Extracting the value from xml that has a given attribute with a value, and then getting the value of the other attribute

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table with a XML column type.

How do I find the value for the car node with name "Ford"?

Also, if Ford is not there, it shouldn't throw an error.

```
    <cars>
      <car name="Honda" value="11" />
      <car name="Toyota" value="22" />
      <car name="Ford" value="3333" />
      <car name="Ferarri" value="444" />
    </cars>
```

I'm not sure how to set the value of the node attribute and then check the next 'value'?

```
XmlColumn.value('/cars[1]/car[1]/@name["Ford"]/@value', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

I'm trying to do the above, but that is a bad query syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another version to try. I also added another row to the table with XML without Ford.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xml_data)
VALUES
(N'<cars>
      <car name="Honda" value="11" />
      <car name="Toyota" value="22" />
      <car name="Ford" value="3333" />
      <car name="Ferarri" value="444" />
    </cars>')
, (N'<cars>
      <car name="Honda" value="11" />
      <car name="Toyota" value="22" />
      <car name="Ferarri" value="444" />
    </cars>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT id, [xml_data].value('(/cars/car[@name="Ford"]/@value)[1]','INT') AS [value]
FROM @tbl AS tbl;
```

> Output

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
|  1 | 3333  |
|  2 | NULL  |
+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to provide a DDL and sample data population when asking a question. Your initial XPath is definitely off.
In your case `CROSS APPLY` is needed to achieve what you need. Check it out:

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xml_data XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xml_data)
VALUES
(N'<cars>
      <car name="Honda" value="11" />
      <car name="Toyota" value="22" />
      <car name="Ford" value="3333" />
      <car name="Ferarri" value="444" />
    </cars>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT col.value('@value','INT') AS [value]
FROM @tbl AS tbl
    CROSS APPLY tbl.[xml_data].nodes('/cars/car[@name="Ford"]') AS tab(col);
```

> Output

```
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|  3333 |
+-------+
```

Comment: can I do this in a single call like I was doing?

Comment: Your idea will work with a variable of XML data type. That's why it is a must to provide a DDL and sample data population.

Comment: My question says 'xml column' type in the first sentence, but good point!